# Controlling CityGML performance?

Tags: fme-form, performance, citygml

I tried to convert single LOD3 building using FME. I am able to convert successfully from DGN to cityGML format.But when I tried to view the same in FZKViewer/FME data inspector the performance is very slow. It takes more time to navigate.

Is there any way to control this?

Comment: What's the size of the CityGML file? If it's slow to view in two different applications I'm assuming the size or complexity of the data is the reason. Maybe the textures are too large? What texture format are you writing? The FME log when reading the data (either in the Data Inspector or when read in Workbench) may provide some clues as to why it's slow.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for the response. The file size is 121MB and I applied texture to the building only (JPEG). Is it size causing issue?